# embad Javascript id based form in runtime Material tabs

Tags: javascript, angular

One JavaScript library is constructing a form under DIV which is ID based.

Example: `<div class="config-options" id="config-options-task-1">`

This needs to to be in runtime in tab structure angular and every time DIV `class="config-options" id="config-options-task-1">` should inject in tab 2 also not with ID changed

This code doesn't load runtime div data on each tab click.

I need help, on this to run this. Any more information?